# LazColumn not scrolling to the bottom of the items list with Compose content into chained element into ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I'm sorry for the long title, but it's a little difficult to explain.

I have a LazyColumn Composable into a FragmentContainerView. This container at the same time into a ConstraintLayout, sharing the space with another container.

This is the activity layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/containerAddModule"
        android:name="com.example.AddModuleFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/containerListModules"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_module" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/containerListModules"
        android:name="com.example.ModulesListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/containerAddModule"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_item_list" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Both container are organized with a vertical chain with weighted heights.

This is the fragment_item_list layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/compose_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And this is the Composable content for the compose_view:

```kotlin
        binding.composeView.setContent {
            val listaModulos = viewModel.allModules.observeAsState(emptyList())
            MaterialTheme {
                Surface() {
                    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
                        items(50) { index ->
                            Text("Test $index")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

With this approach, when scrolling down the LazyColumn, i can only display to the item 39. I cant see 11 items...

On the other hand, using a LinearLayout instead of Constraint Layout in the main layout it works right...

Someone can explain this?